# Terraform fails to launch ec2 instance - Suspect lack of IAM rights for checking instance health

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Which *iam* rights are required for terraform to check instance health during *aws_instance* creation?

I'm seeing this error:

```
* aws_instance.myinstance: Error waiting for instance (i-*********) to become ready:
Failed to reach target state. 
Reason: Client.InternalError: Client error on launch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing the plan with `TF_LOG=DEBUG` will print the API Reply, and this reply mentions the missing Right.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Determining a minimal IAM policy required to perform a terraform run](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2834) someone created a great list [mapping actions to rights](https://pastebin.com/Xm39eh9q)